# Inconsistent accessibility error, access to one class instance from 2 forms

Tags: c#

I have 2 forms and class Model, I need access to same model from both forms
but I got error

```
Error   CS0051  Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Model' is less accessible than method 'MessageForm.MessageForm(Model)'
```

Message form

```
public partial class MessageForm : Form
{
    Model model;

    public MessageForm(Model model)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.model = model;
    }
 }
```

Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MessageForm messageForm;
    Model model;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        model = new Model();
        messageForm = new MessageForm(model);
        messageForm.Show();
   }
}
```

I did same in my other project and that worked fine, I have no idea where is wrong access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `MessageForm` class is `public`, every type that is exposed to the outside must be `public` too.

In this case, your `Model model` constructor parameter is the problem, since `Model` is not `public`. A class from the outside without access to the `Model` class can't access or instantiate the `MessageForm` class since it can't know all types.

The `Model model` in `Form1` isn't exposed to the outside. Hence, it is no issue using it.

Comment: Is there any other way to access class model from both forms?

Comment: When I do that I get another accessibility error in form1   `Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'Model' is less accessible than field 'Form1.model'`        and `Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Model' is less accessible than method 'MessageForm.MessageForm(Model)' `

Comment: Change the `Model` class, not the field.